# OAM assembly code error

Tags: assembly, error-handling, oam

I cannot seem to calculate regular pay in this code. It simply computes the rate of overtime hours not the complete pay including regular pay. [Here](http://compepi.cs.uiowa.edu/cgi-bin/OAMulator2.cgi) is the link to the OAMulator compiler.

```
SET 40     #put the value 40 into the accumulator
STA 50    #store the value 40 in address 50  (I chose 50 arbitrarily)
SET 1.5    #put the value 1.5 into the accumulator
STA 51    #store the value 1.5 in address 51
LDA 0      #input the number of hours worked
STA 52    #store the number of hours worked in address 52
LDA 0      #input the payrate
STA 53    #store the payrate at address 53
LDA 52   #load the number of hours worked into the accumulator
SUB 50   #subtract the number 40 (stored in address 50)
STA 54   #store overtime hours at address 54 
BRP RT   #if hours is more than 40, branch to overtime
LDA 50   #load 40 into the accumulator
MLT 53  #multiply by the payrate.
STA 55  #store REGULAR PAY pay in address 55
RT, LDA 52   #load the number of hours worked
LDA 54  #overtime hours
MLT 51 #overtime rate 
MLT 53 #payrate 
ADD 55 #add the regular pay 
STA 56 #all of the pay
BR FINAL  #branch to where you are going to print the week's pay
STA 56  #store total pay including regular pay and overtime pay in address 56
FINAL,STA 0  #output final pay
HLT
```

What's wrong here, and how can I fix it?

Comment: the program will not output the total pay when overtime hours are inputed. I cannot seem to figure out where the error is.

Answer (score 0):

```
BRP RT   #if hours is more than 40, branch to overtime
```

This branch skips past the code that calculates the regular pay if the number of worked hours exceeds 40. So what you're currently doing is something like this:

```
if (overtime_hours <= 0) {
    regular_pay = 40 * pay_rate;
}
// Here regular_pay might not have been calculated
total_pay = overtime_hours * overtime_rate * pay_rate + regular_pay;
```

When what you actually want probably is something like this:

```
regular_pay = 40 * pay_rate;
total_pay = regular_pay;
if (overtime_hours > 0) {
    total_pay = total_pay + overtime_hours * overtime_rate * pay_rate;
}
```

Comment: @GitaarLAB: It's C, which I used as "pseudo" code to point out the logical flaw in the OP's code, and to suggest a more appropriate code flow. I'll leave it to the OP to do the actual assembly code changes.